# Jump discontinuities in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

I would like to find discontinuities of the first kind of the function:

```
Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]] = f(x)
```

given a specific interval. For example: how to compute the discontinuities of f(x) in the interval [2,3]? If it's even possible.

Comment: Yes I already tried this..  But it runs for 30 minutes without any result. So I think that it didn't work fine.. I used ResourceFunction["FunctionDiscontinuities"][Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]] && 2<=x<=3,x]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
FunctionDomain[{D[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], x], 2 < x < 3}, x]
(*2 < x < 9/4 || 9/4 < x < 5/2 || 5/2 < x < 13/5 || 13/5 < x < 14/5 ||14/5 < x < 3*)
```

Comment: Fantastic! 9/4,5/2,13/5,14/5 are in fact the discontinuities between 2 and 3. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: -1. Indeed fantastic. Think of `RealAbs[x]` where its derivative does not exist at the origin, but the function is continuous at the origin.

Comment: The correct realization of the proposed idea is as follows: `Reduce[D[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], x] == 0 && x >= 19/10 && 
  x <= 31/10, x]` and then consider `Limit[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]],x->2]` and so on. It should be noticed that way is not automatic.

Answer (score 7):

This works in version 13 on Windows 10.

```
FunctionDiscontinuities[{Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], x >= 2 && x <= 3}, x]
```

> `Sin[\[Pi] x] == 0 || Sin[\[Pi] x Floor[x]] == 0 ||  Sin[\[Pi] x Floor[x Floor[x]]] == 0`

and a warning.

```
Solve[% && x >= 2 && x <= 3, x]
```

> `{{x -> 2}, {x -> 9/4}, {x -> 5/2}, {x -> 13/5}, {x -> 14/5}, {x -> 3}}`

Comment: `Plot[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], {x, 1.5, 3.5}]` confirms it.

Comment: To not get a warning, just remove `` x >= 2 && x <= 3`` from ``FunctionDiscontinuities[{Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], x >= 2 && x <= 3}, x]`` and then apply command ``Solve``.

Answer (score 5):

Or simply

```
pw = PiecewiseExpand[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], 
           Assumptions -> 2 < x < 3]
```

[image]

Comment: 1. `PiecewiseExpand[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], 
 Assumptions -> 2 <= x <= 3]` does not show the discontinuity at `x==2`. 2. Some additional work after `PiecewiseExpand` should be done by hand.

Comment: @user64494 `PiecewiseExpand[Floor[x*Floor[x*Floor[x]]], Assumptions -> 1 <= x <= 3]` shows the discontinuity at `x==2`.